# How to get the native pixel format?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, graphics, sdl

Either when I use `glDrawPixel` or some SDL wrapper functions of it, I need to pass the pixel format. I'd like to pass the native pixel format to avoid the conversions. Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) used BGRA (ABGR?) when I checked, but what is a portable way to detect this?

<edit>
I got a small sub-question from a comment. Assuming either ABGR or BGRA pixel format, if the `Ashift` value is 24 that you have to `>> 24` to get the alpha value, is this pixel format **A**BGR or BGR**A**? `Ashift == 0` would be the opposite case.

</edit>

Comment: `SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat` maybe of use for you, https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowPixelFormat

Comment: Newer versions of GL have [image format queries](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Image_format_queries), which will tell you the implementation's preferred pixel format. That's the portable way to detect it, but since it requires GL 4.3, probably not as portable in practice as in theory :P